# Represent Hexadecimal value 0 in python

Tags: python, format, hex

I'm playing with exploiting, and i have a big problem: 
I was practise the ROP technique, and i need to redirect EIP to a ROP Gadget into the binary. 
I'm on a x64 Linux Ubuntu.
The address of my ROP is 0x400559 (offset from the binary), so i have to overwrite the right value with 0x000000400559 (48 bit address), but the return address into the stack is something like 0x7fffffXXXXXX.

My aim is to overwrite 0x7fffffXXXXXX with 0x000000400559, ma the problem are the zeroS. I have to write 0s into insted of 7ff.... but i can't with python.

The simples not working form:

```
./run (python -c "print 'A'*264+'\x59\x05\x40'")
```

What i need is something like this:

```
./run (python -c "print 'A'*264+'\x59\x05\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00'")
```

But \x00 is not working, i also tried hex(0) but nothing ......

What i can do so that i can write 0s into memory ?

Thanxs in advance

Comment: Have you tried piping it to **xxd** or **hexdump** or similar? You may not see some things in terminal output but they're there: **python -c "import sys; sys.stdout.write('A'*264+'\x59\x05\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00')" | xxd**

Comment: Good idea but i don't need the raw hex ... Doesn't exist any ascii representation of \x00 (xxd represent 00 with '..', but they don't represent 0s), i need some escamotage that i can't find

Comment: xxd shows . in output to the right because \x00 is a non-printable character... You can dump the range \x00 - \xFF like this and view it as a series of bits on left if you prefer to see it that way as a form of verification **python -c "import sys; sys.stdout.write(''.join(map(chr,range(0,256))))" | xxd -b -c 8**  (\x00 is correct)

Comment: What i need is an ASCII that represents the \x00, but it doesn't exist, so i think it's not possible..... i tried your code (and thanks for help) and yes, it represents bits 0s as it is \x00, but i can't pass as an argument to a binary, i need an ASCII for exploiting. For example A become 41, B --> 42 etc,... if i have to forme an address with also 0s i need something that represent 00..